# What is a Chartered Scientist/Engineer & how do you become one?

Tags: titles, career-path, professional-association

British societies (and commonwealth countries) offer the title of `chartered scientist/engineer`.

1. Is it based on my education only or work experiences (and research outcome such as publications)? How do they judge an application?
2. Do they need a final degree for the process: do they just contact my university to verify the degree or must I have obtained the degree from specific universities (e.g., accredited programs)?
3. Is this British professional qualification useful outside the commonwealth countries? For instance if applying for a job in US or Germany?

Comment: This varies from country to country, and depends on the specific society you want to join. Each society has specific requirements for membership on their website, so there is no one answer to this question. For the most accurate information, you need to do the reading yourself for each society you want to join.

Comment: This page might be useful: http://www.ima.org.uk/membership/becoming_chartered.cfm.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm basing my answer on Ireland, where my Brother became a [Chartered Engineer](http://www.engineersireland.ie/Membership/Registered-Titles/Chartered.aspx).

In relation to the points of your question.

1. Normally in Ireland you obtain a Bachelors (Hon) degree (up to 2012 now a masters degree) and can become an Associate member of the Engineer Institute. After a period of time, or either further study or in the workplace you may apply to become a Chartered Engineer [Regulations here](http://www.engineersireland.ie/Membership/Registered-Titles/Chartered/how-to-apply.aspx). I know in my brothers case for his application he had to write up any course he took after becoming a member and also any details of any project that he worked on.
2. It appears a masters degree is needed now but a Bachelors (Hon) degree awarded up to 2012 will be accepted up to 2020. Page 7 of the regulations linked above have details of progression routes available.
3. There are a number of [accords](http://www.ieagreements.org/) that ensure cross-border recognition of the qualification. Again as an example, my Brother was able to secure a Engineering Job with a European multinational Engineering firm in the UAE within about 6-8 weeks of moving there.

It is possible that the Irish and British systems are similar due to the historical link between the two countries. Unfortunately as per your question I have no information on the term Chartered Scientist.